# Вывести множество значений в ячейку sql-server

Tags: sql-server

Нужно вывести информацию о заказе - id заказа | информация о заказе

Информация о заказа должно быть одной ячейкой.
Пример:

<Имя товара> Количество: <количество в заказе> шт.

<Имя товара> Количество: <количество в заказе> шт.

<Имя товара> Количество: <количество в заказе> шт.

....

Как это сделать? Вот табличка, откуда берется информация

[image: Табличка]

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: @Akina кажется речь про `concat` обычный

Comment: @teran тоже так думал, но не могу приложить ума, как это сделать так, чтобы применить `concat` ко всем записям так, как нужно

Comment: @Shad0wCloud так у вас в таблице этой небось еще есть столбец с количеством? наименования то вроде уникальные в рамках заказа?

Comment: @teran увы, нет, на фото полная таблица

Comment: версия MS SQL ?

Comment: @teran ms sql 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в общем говоря, будем считать, что если в данной таблице какого-то товара в заказе несколько штук, то этому соответствует несколько одинаковых строк (так вообще не делают). Тогда сначала считаем количество товара в каждом. Потом формируем строк (можете и в одной cte)

```
WITH  qdata AS (
    SELECT order_id, name, count(name) AS qty
    FROM t
    GROUP BY order_id, name
),
data AS (
    SELECT order_id, CONCAT(name,  ' количество ' , qty) AS x
    FROM qdata
)
```

Далее в новых версиях 2017+ использует `string_agg`

```
SELECT order_id, string_agg(x, ', ')
FROM data
GROUP BY order_id
```

в старых обычно сей вопрос решают через XML - либо подзапросом, либо через cross apply. получаем что-то вроде

```
SELECT order_id, LEFT(res, len(res)-1) AS res
FROM data AS t1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT x + ',' 
    FROM data  AS t2
    WHERE t2.order_id = t1.order_id
    FOR XML PATH('')
) AS z (res)
GROUP BY order_id, res
```

вместо запятых, вам видимо потребуется `char(13)`

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее!